# Getting coordinates back from Google Maps iframe in HTML webpage

Tags: php, javascript, html, maps

I currently have a Google Maps window (iframe) embedded in my HTML page, I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve the coordinates every time the user clicks on the map. Is this possible? Should I be using JavaScript to do this?

I was also wondering if I can disable the pop-ups from the map that come up when I click on designated landmarks.

This is the very beginning of what I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Tour Creator</h1>

<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=41.807933,-72.249892&amp;spn=0.015754,0.033023&amp;t=h&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=41.807933,-72.249892&amp;spn=0.015754,0.033023&amp;t=h&amp;z=16&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use the actual maps API, not just an embedded map.

Check out the API docs here - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Use the api, is your best bet, if you manage to hack the values out of a dom or a javascript variable (unlikely), it is possible that you won't get the guarantee that google will keep the coordinates in that location, and of course, there will be no documentation, your code will be unreliable if you get the value somewhere else.